# Can a UserControl be saved as XAML at runtime in WPF?

Tags: wpf, user-controls, save

I have a `UserControl` that includes `Labels`, `TextBox` and `Charts` (generic types). After the user loads this control in a grid at runtime, can it be saved as XAML? So a later user can load his file and edit it. If the `UserControl` cannot be saved as XAML what is the other way to save it?

Thanks for any inputs,

Answer (score 0):

I think you will want to look at the [`XamlWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlwriter.aspx) / [`XamlReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlreader.aspx) Classes. There are some [limitations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754193.aspx) but they might work for you.